# Table View Cell Formatting

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am playing around with the Apple Dev tutorial on the to do list, trying to morph it into something for deliveries at my work. I have been working on the formatting of the NSString location, and NSNumber's total, tip, and percentage for hours, with no luck. I am trying to get just the data, not the headers to be right aligned. I tried creating two cells (in the commented code) but this "prototype cell" in the storyboard just overrides it, and provides the prototype cell text I have in the storyboard "Mow the Lawn" instead. Any suggestions?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"ListPrototypeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;  // 0 means no max.
    tableView.rowHeight = 100;

    ToDoItem *toDoItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.roundingIncrement = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.01];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

    NSNumberFormatter *percentageFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    //NSString *detailText = @"Location: @\nTotal: @\nTip: \nPercentage: %%";

    if(toDoItem.isCreditCard)
    {
      cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Location: %10@\nTotal: %10@\nTip: %@\nPercentage: %@%%", toDoItem.location, [formatter stringFromNumber:toDoItem.total], [formatter stringFromNumber:toDoItem.tip],[percentageFormatter stringFromNumber:toDoItem.percentage]];
         cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Credit Card";
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Location: %10@\nTotal: %10@\nTip: %@\nPercentage: %@%%", toDoItem.location, [formatter stringFromNumber:toDoItem.total], [formatter stringFromNumber:toDoItem.tip],[percentageFormatter stringFromNumber:toDoItem.percentage]];
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Location: @\nTotal: @\nTip: \nPercentage: %%";
        //cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
    }

  /*  UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    lbl.text = @"Location: @\nTotal: @\nTip: \nPercentage: %%";
    [lbl setFrame:cell.textLabel.frame];// set frame which you want
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];// set any color here
    //                 lbl.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap; // set it if you want to height of UILable with its content (Multiple line)
    lbl.numberOfLines = 0;// Add this line // Set 0 if you want to multiple line.
    lbl.textAlignment =  NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];

    UILabel *lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    lbl2.text = @"test2";
   // LogCGRect(cell.textLabel.frame);
    [lbl2 setFrame:cell.textLabel.frame];// set frame which you want
    [lbl2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];// set any color here
    //                 lbl.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap; // set it if you want to height of UILable with its content (Multiple line)
    lbl2.numberOfLines = 2;// Add this line // Set 0 if you want to multiple line.
    lbl2.textAlignment =  NSTextAlignmentRight;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl2];
  */ 
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: add an if condition for each one based on some value you might have lets say.. if(value ==  '1') { thisCell } else if ( value == 2) { thisCell } else { defaultCell}

Comment: call the UITableviewCell when you need it and return it. but always have a else so if none of your conditions match your tableview still can show a default tableViewCell.. read more about Custom Table View cells

Comment: Ok I will add that in, but do you have any suggestions about how to right align the data?

Comment: If you want to visually arrange data to maintain at a specific place you may need to use Constrains, You can find that on your StoryBoard